# Filter data for different data serie to display in XY-Plot

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to paste the date (see image) in my excel sheet a get a XY-Plot with 4 data series, one for each `Method`
Until now I filter them by Method and copy each result, so I get 4 tables for 4 data series.

Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Sort your table on `Method` (primary) then `DateTime` (secondary).
Now you have four tables, one for each method.
Define ranges for each method by marking each **separately** while holding down the `CTRL`-key.
*Note the difference: Do not mark all in one go.*
Create your graph.

*UNTESTED: I do not have access to Excel, otherwise I would have tried it out*

Comment: Thy for our answer. I did't want to set the range each time I paste new data. The amount of data is volatile, so the range would be different each time.

Comment: i.e. the source data for each set will vary in size. One way: You will have to use a temporary table that copies the data you have, sort that table as described above, then sift through it to determine what data range belongs into each data-set (one XY-curve), then re-create the diagram - assuming VBA. I suspect this will not be possible without VBA. This is far from trivial. Stop.